# How to select and shade polygons I am interested based on existing shapefile in ArcGIS 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, arcgis-10.2

The shapefile already includes polygons I am interested and others.  I want to make a map put in my paper showing which regions in the world I am interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If, in the shape file, there is an attribute that you are interested in, or can otherwise search on, use Version 2 (it's safer), otherwise use Version 1.:

**Version 1:**

1. Open the Attribute Table for the shape file.
2. Add a new Field (under Table Options).
3. Name it "Interested" or something.  Short Integer is fine.
4. Go into Editing mode and make sure to select your shape file from the list.  Be careful while in Editing mode, you can really screw things up with your shape file here.
5. Double click on the cells in the Attribute Table under the new column and add a 1 if you want to color it, or a 0 if you don't.
6. Save edits and stop editing.
7. Close the Attribute Table.
8. Open up the Layer Properties for your shape file.
9. Go to the Symbology Tab.
10. Use the Categories -> Unique Values option
11. Under the Value Field, select the column that you added earlier (in this case, "Interested")
12. Click "Add All Values"
13. Change the colors to whatever you want.  There should only be two options, 1 and 0.
14. Apply and done.

**Version 2:**

1. Right click on your shape file in the Table of Contents (TOC) and "Copy" it.
2. Right click on the "Layers" heading in the TOC and click "Paste Layers".
3. On one of the two identical layers, open up the Layer Properties.
4. Click on the "Definition Query" tab.
5. Click on "Query Builder".
6. Building a query using this tab.  Example would be "[Id] <= 5".  More information on this can be found on the Arc Help site [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s50000002z000000) and [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Building_a_query_expression/00s50000002t000000/).
7. Click "OK"
8. Go to the Symbology tab.  Color this layer as you wish.
9. Repeat steps 3-8 for the other layer created, just reverse the formula in step 6. E.g. "[Id] > 5"

Comment: I tried version 2 and it works.  Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 4):

The solution of @Josh is good. If you are interested only in few polygons this approach perhaps is more quickly:

1. Select polygons you are interested in with your mouse (in map)
2. Right click on polygon layer in TOC. Chose *Selection* > Create *Layer From
   Selected Features*

Comment: Forgot you could do that.  That's probably better for the OP's specific use case I'd imagine.